# Why [object Object] mentions "object" twice?

Tags: javascript, json, object

[object Object] is the default string representation of a JavaScript Object.

I would understand if it was just `[Object]` or `[object]`, but why `[object Object]`? Why the first word is lowercase and the second one is uppercase? Is it part of JSON or JavaScript?

Comment: _If this method is not overridden in a custom object, toString() returns "[object type]", where type is the object type._ ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString))

Comment: For the same reason that `[object RegExp]` or `[object Array]` has `object` in it: because it is an `object`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

All objects have a `toString` method that displays something in the format `[object type]`, where type is the object type.

When called on `null` you get `[object Null]` and when called on an object you get the string `[object Object]` because it's based on the [Object constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) (capital "O"), that's why it says `object` twice, it's an object *of the type* Object.

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

JSON is a lightweight data-interchange format, and doesn't really have anything to do with JavaScript other than being named *"JavaScript Object Notation"* because it's written like a JavaScript object.

Comment: @Oriol - No, all objects have a `toString` method, the only way they wouldn't is if you specifically overwrite it with something else (and technically they still would), and that's not really relevant. The second word is the type of object, also refered to as a  class, and it doesn't really have anything to do with primitives ?

Comment: I was thinking `Object.create(null)`, which has no property. And about the 2nd word: if `Object.prototype.toString` is called on a primitive, it will be its type; if it's called on an object, it will be it's [[Class]] (e.g. Object, Array, Date), not its type (always Object). Just nitpicking :)

Comment: `Object.create(null)` is a very special case, it's the only way to create something resembling an object that doesn't inherit from anywhere and thus has no properties. `Object.prototype.toString` is probably even more special, as it's a prototype of the Object constructor and can't be called on anything but an object, unless you go out of your way and do `Object.prototype.toString.call` on a primitive, and you'd probably still get `[object String]` etc. These are so far fetched edge cases that even MDN has decided to leave them out.

Answer (score 15):

> I would understand if it was just [Object] or [object], but why [object Object]?

Because it is *an object* created from the basic `Object` class.

From [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2):

> Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings "[object ", class, and "]".

---

> Is it part of JSON or JavaScript?

It has absolutely nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 10):

The first `object` denotes that the type of the thing being logged is an object. It's also hard-coded in the language specification [here](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2).

The second `Object` denotes the constructor property, for example:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(""); // [object String]
```

The algorithm just says: "Get the [[class]] property of the object and then return '[object ' + class + ']'.

Answer (score 3):

You've basically hit the platonic wall end of the cave. If everything is an object, what is the superset of object? Here, the answer is embodied in the code, it is simply object.

Hence all Objects are objects.

Welcome to the circularity.