# Why do I get this [object Object] and not just "object" i.e. just its type?

Tags: javascript

why i get this [object Object] and not just "object" i.e. just its type?

```js
var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  eyeColor: "blue"
};
var person;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person + "<br>" + typeof person;
```

```html
<p>Variables can be emptied by setting the value to <b>undefined</b>.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Is this even a question? The content of your question makes no sense. Are you asking or telling?

Comment: @Snowmonkey It was unformatted code. Of course, still not really a question.

Comment: So, once again, what exactly is the bug/glitch/question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Also a dupe of [What does `[object Object]` mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4750225/4642212) or [Why `[object Object]` mentions “object” twice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29847665/4642212), depending on what the actual question is. Why did you expect anything else, let alone the type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does \[object Object\] mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean)

Comment: I have edited it .. you can see the it now.

Comment: run the javascript portion of that directly in your console, you'll see that what you actually get is      Object {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: 50, eyeColor: "blue"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are concatenating `person` with `"<br />"`. In that process, `person` is converted to a string. The default string representation of an object is `[object Object]`.

If you wrote

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = typeof person;
```

instead, then you'd only get `object`.